# Angular pop under ads setup for all pages

Tags: angular, single-page-application, ads

I am trying to show popunder ads in my angular web app. I have included the script file in the  section. The pop-under is showing correctly only on the home page. When I navigate to other pages, there is no popup is showing. I think it is because, the web app is angular, so the page changes are not detected by the script. is there some way to show pop-under ads on all the pages? the script tag is given below

```
<script>
   (function(s,u,z,p){s.src=u,s.setAttribute('data-zone',z),p.appendChild(s);})(document.createElement('script'),'https://iclickcdn.com/tag.min.js',12654***,document.body||document.documentElement)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="home">Home</a>`
Use the href type of routes instead of routerLink

```
<a routerLink="home">Home>/a>
```